# Testing metasearch / ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, meta-search

Is there a way to test a metasearch form in rails to see if the returned results are expected?

For example I want to do a

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :supplier_name_contains %>
      <%= f.text_field :supplier_name_contains %>
    </p>
     <p class="button"><%= f.submit "Search" %></p> 
<% end %>
```

and rest the results to see that they do in fact contain the specified text. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not automated testing, but you could use

```
<p>SQL: <%= @objects.to_sql %></p>
```

which displays the corresponding SQL query.

Comment: Yeah that could work, not really the answer I was looking for so won't accept it, but thanks. Upvoted :)